# Click and type (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, types, click

I was using an Adobe product (If I remember correctly, it was a PDF Creator) the other day, and they have this cool feature where you can literally click anywhere inside the window and just start typing. And the text will appear as you type, whereever you clicked.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction where I can learn how to implement something like this?

Thank you

**Edit**:

---

Steps to Click & Type:

1. Capture MouseDown and store location where user clicked.
2. Handle KeyDown event to see what key was pressed.
3. Foreach key that is pressed, create a label and place it next to the last-typed character.

@Qua, in the last step, am I right in thinking that? If so, how would I account for the length of an individual character, so I know where to place the next one? I think I would need to somehow measure the type and size of the font in the label and adjust positioning accordingly...?

Comment: Please don't create one label per keystroke.  Instead, create a textbox that's styled to match your background.  Make it transparent if needed (it's tricky, but possible, and still better than a bunch of labels), but styling to match the background is often much simpler.

Comment: Thank you Joel. I've just realised that I can make textbox controls Transparent by setting their background to "Black" since I'm using the ExtendedWindowsGlass feature :)

Comment: Is it your goal ... for the user at run-time ... to "type anywhere," but not be able to edit : lose the ability to delete text by backspacing; lose the abliity to use copy, paste, and cut ? Does it matter that you might end up with "lots" of individual label objects which would not editable at run-time ? Do you care if you end up with a bunch of textboxes, which do not support auto-size, which can be edited at run-time, but have no : "inherent sequential relationship" with each other ? Might help if you clarify your "real world" goal further here.

Comment: @BillW. I would like my users to be able to click anywhere and just start typing, then if they choose, to be able to edit that text, and/or delete it, change the Font and Color of that text and the style properties for that text, too.

Comment: Then, imho, you need to create an auto-resizing RichTextBox. And when the end-user is typing away : under what circumstances would you want want scrollbars to appear in the RichTextBox rather than the RichTextBox resize ? What happens (if you don't want scrollbars to appear) when the user starts typing near the right edge of the page, and then types "off the edge of the page" ? imho you need to get more specific about what you want here. Editing font, color, and style requires a RichTextBox (unless you want to go 'insane' using GDI+ :)

Comment: If you really must use an auto-resizing RichTextBox, and I strongly suggest you reconsider you whole strategy here, you are going to have to get "down and dirty" with API calls : this may get you started : http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/winform-controls/5064/using-EM-GETRECT-vs-using-EM-GETLINECOUNT-with-a-RichTextBox ... and ... http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/winform-controls/5060/Detecting-word-wrap-in-a-TextBox-or-RichTextBox-control ... I gave up on the idea, decided that doing this was bad design in the first place. Good luck, though !

Comment: An alternative ? After the user clicks a toolstrip icon : on the next Form MouseDown : insert new RichTextBox (RTB) on the Form where they clicked, show your menu for changing Font, etc. Enable resize or move of the RTB at any time. Example : trap the MouseDown on the RTB in combination with ControlKey-down, then move the RTB when the left mouse button moves, resize when the right mouse button moves. Using a ControlKey-down constraint means you won't lose using a right-click context menu. Downside : no auto-resize ? Upside : user can resize or move at any time ? Want to see code ? Ask.

Comment: Hmm, If only there were any easier way... Could you kindly provide some code? :)

Comment: @j-t-s Still, imho, need to know if you must have an auto-resizing RichTextBox, and an individual RichTextBox for every place the user clicks . Consider that you could create one RichTextBox in a Form, set its DockStyle to 'Fill, then, in the Form Load event, "fill" the RTB with spaces and carriage returns : at that point the user could click with the mouse and set the insertion point anywhere, and start typing. But what will happen is that starting to type before content you've already added may cause may cause re-location of that content. Could you live with that ?

Comment: by the sounds of it going insane with GDI+ will be the way to go

Answer (score 1):

You could simply draw a new TextBox on your Windows Form when the user clicks.  The MouseClick event will expose all the properties you need to draw the textbox right where they click.

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
    txtBox.Location = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    this.Controls.Add(txtBox);
    txtBox.Focus();
}
```

You could make the TextBox transparent or what not if you wanted to mask the fact that they're typing a normal TextBox.

Comment: Note that TextBoxes do not have an Auto-Size property : at run-time how does the end user get a TextBox large enough (or small enough) to contain only the text the user typed. This requires creating an auto-resizing TextBox control which is doable, but not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you wanted to implement this feature on a usercontrol that you were making. At first you would need to handle the mouse down event to register where the user clicked, and after this you should be able to handle the key down event to register which keys the user pressed.

To draw the actual text at the target location you have several options. You could use GDI+ to render the strings on the control or you could insert labels which would benefit you due to the amount of functionality that the labels come with.

Here's a prototype example of how it could be implemented using GDI:

```
private Point? lastSelected;
private Dictionary<Point, string> renderedText = new Dictionary<Point, string>();

private Point LastSelected
{
    get
    {
        return (Point)lastSelected;
    }
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MouseDown += Form1_MouseDown;
    this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
    this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
}

void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Point, string> pair in renderedText)
{
        e.Graphics.DrawString(pair.Value, new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, 

pair.Key);
    }
   }

   void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
    if (lastSelected != null)
    {
        if (!renderedText.ContainsKey(LastSelected))
        {
            renderedText.Add(LastSelected, "");
        }
        renderedText[LastSelected] = renderedText[LastSelected] + e.KeyCode;
        this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lastSelected = e.Location;
}
```

---

**Reply to comment:**

The above code captures the location of the mouse when the user clicks on the form and saves it in the lastSelected variable. At each subsequent key press on the form the key pressed is appended to the string representing that location. Furthermore the strings are being rendered on the screen at the captured location in the paint. The strings are rendered using GDI+, which means that you don't need to worry about the length of the individual characters.

Note that for a real application storing the locations and strings via a hashtabel (dictionary in C#) is not a great idea. You should rather create a custom class or structure that will hold the information such as location, text ect. This will allow you to further improve the functionality by adding options for stuff like bolding, italic, font sizes and so on.

Comment: Oh this is awesome, I'm about to update my question, can you please take a look at it and tell me if I'm right in what I'm saying? I'd type it here, but it'll be too long and messy as a comment

Comment: Edited to respond to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) I am now trying to reduce the flickering, it's really bad flickering, like it's trying to jump out of the screen or something and attack me. But very much appreciated :-D

Comment: At run-time : once the strings are rendered via GDI+, they are, of course, just a buch of "burned pixels" : not editable, you can't move them arond as "objects." Seems like a highly implausible scenario.